# Azure DevOps profile pictures not displayed on boards

Tags: image, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, profile, azure-boards

With our small development team, we recently switched to Azure DevOps. I successfully connected our tenant to DevOps, in the sense that users are available. From other posts, I understand that profile pictures are not automatically synchronized, and that each user needs to add their own profile picture in DevOps. However, even after doing so, the profile pictures do not appear in all places. Most crucially, they do not appear on cards on boards. They do, however, appear in the top right corner and when configuring the team.

Here's a screenshot showing the missing profile picture:
[image: screenshot showing the missing profile picture]

and one showing the profile picture in settings:
[image: showing the profile picture in settings]

I waited for about a week. So I also don't expect this to be related to any waiting period until the server updates.

Is this a bug in DevOps or am I missing some crucial settings?

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

**Solution 1:**

Right clicking on the avatar, choose **Open image in a new tab** and  **right click > refresh**

[image]

[image]

**Solution 2:**

After you change profile pictures in azure devops , you could **clear browser data** or you need to wait for some hours or days to let it change to the new one. And also try with the **another browser window**.

Comment: Hi @ShrutiJoshi-MT,
thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. Sol. 1 refers to the general profile picture in the top right corner. That worked fine anyways and Sol. 1 doesn't make it appear on boards either. 
I already tried Sol. 2 before. In fact, I've been waiting for several weeks, deleted browser cache, tried Chrome, Firefox, and Edge on Windows and Ubuntu. By coincidence, I even setup a completely fresh Windows installation -- unfortunately to no avail. So I'm pretty confident that this issue is related to some Azure configuration and not to the browser. Thanks!

Comment: Clearing my cache worked for me thanks

Comment: Solution 1 & 2 worked together for me.

Refreshed, then Cleared Cache and Reloaded my page. Viola!!! (Chrome)

Answer (score 2):

The solution for ShrutiJoshi-MT almost worked for myself. I had to do a couple more steps:

1. Every single sized version of the picture right click image -> open new tab. Press Shift + F5.
2. When I finished updating the profiles I shift + F5 each page that has the issue as well.

Using Firefox myself.

Comment: I had the similar issue where my image is updated in top right corner but my picture on items on board was stuck to old picture... I just did Shift+F5 in Chrome and the new picture loaded for board items as well. I didn't have to open anything in new tab...